# Analytic function's proof verification - I didnt use all the given condition. Where's the mistake?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, analytic-functions

let $ f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} $ be with positive convergence radius $ R>0 $ and assume that exists sequence $ y_n \in(0,R) $ decreasing monotonic such that  $ y_{n}\to0 $ and for any $ n\in \mathbb{N} $  $ f\left(y_{n}\right)=0 $. we need to prove that $ a_n=0 $ for any $ n\in \mathbb{N} $  what i've done:

prove by induction :

for  $n=0 $ we have $ f\left(0\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}0^{n}=a_{0} $

also the series is cointinious, therefore  $ \lim_{x\to0}f\left(x\right)=f\left(0\right)=a_{0} $

so using Heine's theorem:

$ \lim_{x\to0}f\left(x\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(y_{n}\right)=a_0 $

and since for any $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ $f(y_n)=0 $ we can conclude that $a_0=0 $

Now assume the statement is true for any $n<m$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N} $

So we have:

$ f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}=x^{m}\left(\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n-m}\right) $

let $ k\in\mathbb{N} $. from the given condintions $ f\left(y_{k}\right)=0 $ and $ y_{k}\neq0 $ so

$ f\left(y_{k}\right)=\left(y_{k}\right)^{m}\left(\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_{n}\left(y_{k}\right)^{n-m}\right)=0 $

Thus, we can colclude that $ \sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_{n}\left(y_{k}\right)^{n-m}=0 $ for any $ k\in \mathbb{N} $

Name this function $ g\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n-m} $

and we know that the function is continious, therefore

$ \lim_{x\to0}g\left(x\right)=g\left(0\right)=a_{m} $

and using Heine's theorem once again gives us:

$ \lim_{x\to0}g\left(x\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g\left(y_{n}\right)=a_{m}=0 $

therefore $a_m$ =0

That proves the theorem, but I didnt use the fact that $y_n $ is decreasing. I cant see where I was wrong. any thoughts will be helpful.

Comment: What is your induction ? with respect to what ?

Comment: It is not necessary that $y_n$ is decreasing. As long as $y_n \to 0$ the result is valid. Your proof is correct.

Comment: @Walace you mean where i used the induction hypothesis? its here $ f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}=x^{m}\left(\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n-m}\right) $ thats why i can pull out the $ x^m $

Comment: @Waizman Let me also point out that if $y_n$'s are distinct and $y_n \to 0$ then there exists subsequence decreasing to $0$. So  it obvious tat monotonicity has no relevance here.